# Does "Insert.. on Duplicate" update the entire row, or specific columns?

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

When using in mysql [insert..on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), what happens to the rest of the columns that are not being updated? Do they remain the same? I don't want to erase the rest of the data, only need to make sure certain rows are there (and if they are not, then update them).

I believe that I should not be using [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), which does replace the entire row.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. When using `INSERT..ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`, if the INSERT fails, only the fields explicitly stated in the UPDATE clause are updated. The rest of the fields remain unchanged.